# Multiregional Websites

Tags: multilingual, subdomain

I would like to make a multiregional website but I am having some difficulties. I use cPanel and are laying out the domains as:

- ca.example.com
- usa.example.com
- fr.example.com

I want to know how I would add the subdomains in and be able to use my one custom made php script to run these websites via .htaccess or whatever form.

Comment: Just a side note: do yourself a favor and use proper ISO 3166-1 country codes, such as 'us' rather than 'usa'. It will help you later when you'll want to do mapping to TLDs or geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cPanel's **parked domain** feature. When you park a domain in cPanel, you can point it to the same root as your main domain. In the Parked Domains interface in cPanel, add your language subdomains (e.g. `ca.example.com`). All your language subdomains will then redirect to the same main domain (`example.com`).

Then, you can use PHP's `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` property to parse out the server name the user used to access the page, and in turn render the page in the correct language.

Comment: Actually, I have made a mistake. It is better to create what cPanel calls a "Parked Domain". Create a parked domain for each language (e.g. `ca.example.com`). All your park domains should map to the same root as `example.com`